# Want to understand need of callback functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in learning JavaScript. I read about callback functions but I am unable to understand its real use.

So, please help by any real world example.

Below is small code depicting use of callback function in but that too is not clear to me.

```
var friends = ["Mike", "Stacy", "Andy", "Rick"];
​
friends.forEach(function (eachName, index){
    console.log(index + 1 + ". " + eachName); // 1. Mike, 2. Stacy, 3. Andy, 4. Rick​
});
```

Comment: Read this: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

Comment: Read this: http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/javascript-callbacks/

Comment: I read that both link ...but still not crystal clear about that...can ny one explain by real life problem or example??

Comment: Basically in the code you have provided, a callback function is triggered for each element you iterate through. In your example the callback function will be triggered with the following parameters passed to it per round: the value, and the index. Callbacks are useful because it dramatically reduces the redundancy of your code: you wouldn't want to write a function for each name, do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uses of JavaScript callback functions are many. You probably already know that it's simply a function that we pass as an argument to another function. This means that we can have a function called `foo`. Lets says `foo` is some sort of method that runs an array through a sort, however the actual sorting function is variable. So we could use `foo` for every algorithm, by simply passing values like so.

```
foo([1,6,1,2], quickSort);
```

Assuming we have a quickSort method.

Generally speaking, callbacks are however used to call something AFTER a function has executed. So why not just call one function after the other, you say?

```
foo();
bar();
```

Why would you pass `bar` to `foo` ? Well, usually callbacks are used when dealing with asynchronicity. So, the `bar` function would get called way before, say an AJAX request gets a response, or before a setTimeout triggers it's callback.

As for the specific example you provided, it's simply a simplified way to iterate over an array. With the added benefit that you can use a named function, so you can declare it earlier and separate your code better.

Comment: ...tx for you'r  help....can you please explain in laymen term that what is need tp pass function as parameter to another function???????

Comment: Well, just like any variable, you can name a function( for instance `foo` ) then pass it to a different function 'bar`. 
`bar(foo)`

You can also pass a function directly, by writing it as a parameter, without it's name. This is called an anonymous function:

`bar(function() {
});`

Comment: Again tx for you'r help.....but you didn't understand my question.....I am asking about the need of asynchronous function in laymen term??/Not it's defination..

Comment: Say you want some code to be executed after 10 seconds. For instance, after ten seconds, ask the user to take your survey. You could define a function called `promptUserForSurvey` then `setTimeout(promptUserForSurvey, 10000)`. In this case you'd need the function to be async, since a synchronous function would block execution of the code for 10 seconds, before prompting the user for input. Or with an HTTP request. Say you require some info from the server, if the server response is slow, and the request was sync, then the user would be blocked until the request came through.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is generally synchronous, i.e. commands are executed one after the other.

However there are times where you want a function to be asynchronous, so you call a function and don't want to wait for it to complete before you move on to your next task.

Callbacks are used by asynchronous functions. When the function completes, the callback function is run, without the rest of the code having to wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

var friends = ["Mike", "Stacy", "Andy", "Rick"];           friends.forEach(function (element, index, array) {             console.log((index+1) + "." + element );           });

Answer (score 0):

The concept of Callbacks in JavaScript is that you can assign functions to variables.

Everthing, in JavaScript, except for simple types as string and number, are objects (and even those have functions to be called as they were objects as well).

Let's take your function for instance, as example:

> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> arr.forEach(callback[, thisArg])
> ```
>
> ### Parameters
>
> ```
> callback
> ```
>
> Function to execute for each element, taking three arguments:
>
> ```
> currentValue
> ```
>
> The current element being processed in the array.
>
> ```
>     index
> ```
>
> The index of the current element being processed in the array.
>
> ```
>     array
> ```
>
> The array that forEach is being applied to.
>
> ```
> thisArg
> ```
>
> Optional. Value to use as this when executing callback.

It takes a callback function that will be called for each element.

Also, we have the definitions of asynchronous calls in JS (with a help of timeouts/interval and AJAX calls).

The idea of the callback functions doesn't stays just in JS. Anywhere it would be easier or just simples, to use a function passed as reference we have the concept of callback (it just goes insane with this feature of AJAX in js, that why it's so common to say JS is asynchronous).

You could read a litte more about it here:
http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-goes-asynchronous-awesome/

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript, function below is an object:

```
function (eachName, index){
  console.log(index + 1 + ". " + eachName); // 1. Mike, 2. Stacy, 3. Andy, 4. Rick​
}
```

Let call this `object A`.
When you pass the code `friends.forEach(A)`, browser will understand that when running through the `array friends` it will trigger `A`.

So at the end, callback function is just like you "define" function but you will use it later on.